# how do I detect a word then send a message in a dm with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to detect when a YouTube video link is sent through a dm, is it possible to do this and if so, how?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: @griffin_cosgrove i dont have a lot of experience with discord.py so i couldnt think of anything to try, sorry

Comment: This question is a lot of questions in one. You're asking how to detect when a message is sent, check if it's a dm, and then check if it contains a youtube link. These are all separate problems that you should try to implement and then ask a question for each if your code doesn't work. It's likely that all three of these questions have answers on StackOverflow already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what I understood is right, this should help you. I tried to make it as clear as possible for you to modify the code as you wish

```
client = discord.Client() #Discord Client

@client.event
async def on_message(message): #Event handler for income messages
    if message.author == client.user:  #Stopping the bot from reading its on message
        return None 
    
    word_to_check = 'example' #Word that you want to check in a string
    response = 'this is the response'

    if word_to_check in message.content:    
        await message.channel.send(response) #This responds to the channel the message containing "word_to_check" came from
```